# Форматирование горизонтальной линии работает неправильно

Tags: дефект, форматирование

По [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) вот таким способом `---` можно создать горизонтальную линию:

> [image]

Но отображается она как заголовок:

> [image]

При чём ошибку я заметил только на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы была горизонтальная линия, предыдущая строка должна быть пустой. Я предпочитаю оставлять пустую линию и до, и после.

```
Текст

---
Текст под линией
```

Текст

---

Текст под линией

Comment: Может я что-то путаю, но раньше и без этого работала, нет?

Comment: @Арман, неа, всегда заголовок был.

Comment: Но справка-то всё равно написана криво, в ней пустой строки нет

Comment: @andreymal, в справке есть пример с линией _Для разделения частей текста используйте заголовки:_ - и далее пример с большим и меньшим заголовками

Comment: @Grundy видимо в справке такого примера всё-таки нету, выделенная курсивом часть даже не гуглится вообще

Comment: @andreymal, это из краткой справки, которая в окне редактирование, из большой справки выдержку в ответе добавил :)

Comment: Я тут пересмотрел свой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052443/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9). Там горизонтальная линия написано таким образом как я показал в вопросе, но при попытке редактировать показывается опять же как заголовок.

Comment: @Арман, возможно изменилась обработка пробела перед `---`. Просто дефисы вроде всегда были заголовком. Ну и ещё есть вариант, что в предпросмотре и после сохранения работает по-разному.

Answer (score 4):

В той же [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers) в пункте выше указан пример с заголовками

> Подчеркните текст, чтобы создать два заголовка верхнего уровня <h1> <h2> :
>
> ```
> Заголовок 1
> ========
> Заголовок 2
> --------
> ```

Кроме того, для создания подчеркиваний приведено 4 способа, можно пользоваться любым

> ```
> Правило № 1 // часть совпадающая с предыдущим пунктом
> ---
> Правило № 2
> *******
> Правило № 3
> ___
> ```
>
> Также можно использовать пробелы между символами, это решает проблему выбора между заголовком и горизонтальной линией:
>
> ```
> Rule #4   
> - - - -
> ```

Comment: Я ж говорю справка кривая, под «Правило № 1» не появится никакого подчеркивания

Comment: @andreymal, на самом деле - это не примеры :-) это список правил - если ты напишешь `---` то у тебя вполне может появиться подчеркивание

Comment: Примеры в справке плохие, стоит изменить. Лично я, когда вижу блок кода, полагаю, что могу просто скопировать его.

Comment: @nomnoms12, ты его действительно можешь скопировать `---` и он будет работать.

Comment: @nomnoms12, тут скорее в маркдауне проблема, что у него для разных действий в разных случаях могут применяться одни и те же способы.

Comment: @Grundy и проблема справки в том, что она не уведомляет о проблемах в маркдауне :)

Comment: @Grundy и самое забавное, что об этом [писали на метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61038) аж десять(!) лет назад